# Does Git require an internet connection to work locally?

Tags: git

I am new to Git, trying to learn about it before I can start using it. Does Git always require an internet connection to work locally?

I Googled and found out it can work on a local computer in client-server mode. 
Does it require an internet connection to just work locally on a single computer?

If it doesn't require an internet connection, then why do guides I find via Google tell me to add a username and email address while setting up Git for the first? User name I can understand, but why an email address?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your question a little bit; I've fixed up the grammar (don't worry about that, I understand if you're not a native English speaker), removed some of the chattiness (on StackOverflow, it's recommended to just focus on the question, not apologizing for being a noob or telling people to direct you do other questions if it's been asked), and moved your comment clarifying why you had this concern into the question (the extra information makes it more clear why you were worried that you might need an internet connection).

Comment: Sort of surprised at all the downvotes. It is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I don't know how to react, I am surprised by your kindness to new comers.  
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, an internet connection is not required. You can use Git entirely locally with no network connection. It can be used for a single repository, in which no network connection is used. It can be used to pull from other repositories on the same computer simply by reading from the filesystem, which requires no network connection. You can also use it with a local area network connection but no internet connection, if you want to share between multiple machines but don't have an internet connection. Or if you don't have a network at all, even a local one, you can store repositories on removable media, move them between computers, and pull and push to the repository on the removable medium on each machine.

The name and email address are recorded to store authorship information for each commit. They are simply used to identify who authored or committed each change. If you ever work on a project with more than one person, it's a lot more informative to have authorship information like `My Name <me@example.com>` and `Other Name <someone@example.com>` than it is to see `Administrator <root@machine.local>` or something of the sort. The email address is not actually used for anything other than identification of who committed what.

The reason you don't just use a name is that there can be two people named "Brian Campbell" (in fact, there are a lot of people named "Brian Campbell"). In a distributed revision control system like Git, you also can't just pick a username, because there is no central server that can keep track of all of the usernames, two different people could just pick the same username. Since an email address is a unique identifier that pretty much everyone already has, it acts as a convenient way to pick unique IDs even without a central server.

Comment: Hey thanks alot. Then if doesn't require internet connection then why everybody's telling to add username and email id while setting up GIT the first time in google generally..?
User name I can understand but why Email Id..?

Comment: @raao The name and email address are recorded to store authorship information for each commit. They are simply used to identify who authored or committed each change. If you ever work on a project with more than one person, it's a lot more informative to have authorship information like `My Name <me@example.com` and `Other Name <someone@example.com>` than it is to see `Administrator <root@machine.local>` or something of the sort. The email address is not actually used for anything other than identification of who committed what.

Comment: @raao The reason you don't just use a name is that there can be two people named "Brian Campbell" (in fact, there are a lot of people named "Brian Campbell"). In a distributed revision control system like Git, you also can't just pick a username, because there is no central server that can keep track of all of the usernames, two different people could just pick the same username. Since an email address is a unique identifier that pretty much everyone already has, it acts as a convenient way to pick unique IDs even without a central server.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. That is the point of distributed SCMs.